# Is it likely there are more rogue planets than brown dwarfs, and that we just can't see them because they're too dim?

Tags: light, deep-sky-observing, rogue-planet

Among celestial bodies revolving around the galactic center directly, it seems the bodies of lowest mass (brown and red dwarfs) are the most abundant. However, when it comes to even less massive Y-dwarfs it's very hard to find them because they emit little light. Can we assume that there are actually many more Y-dwarfs and even more rogue planets in comparison to the stellar bodies? Earth-mass rogue planets have been discovered, after all. If no, why do you think it's unlikely?

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/1201.2687